# CRM 2011 and Sharepoint Integration - Missing Images

Tags: dynamics-crm

After finding a post here about doing a single server installation (for my test environment) was a bit backwards; I had CRM installed first then did the Sharepoint install.

While most of it is working correctly, however when I go into an Account and click on Documents the toolbar doesn't load. The images come up with a 404 Not Found. *can't post screenshot it seems :(

Where can I start to remedy this? I haven't been able to find much with my Google-Fu today :(.

Thanks!